# Show LoginView Status in Bootstrap Navigation Bar

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, master-pages, navbar

I am trying to use the template that bootstrap provided but would like to add the login view and login status on the right side of the nav-bar.  I am not able to modify it properly so i can include the login status. please help
here is the master page using bootstrap

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sleep Track</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

here is the login view that i would like to include it

```
<div>
        Welcome
        <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName2" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" />
    <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblLastLoginDate" runat="server" />
        <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" />
        <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server"></asp:LoginView>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the post is old but I have the same issue and I have resolved it after spending quite a bit of time. Hopefully this will help others. What you can do is use the following code.

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <asp:LoginView  ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
     <AnonymousTemplate><li><a href="Register.aspx"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="Login.aspx"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        </AnonymousTemplate>
     <LoggedInTemplate><li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" /></a></li><li><asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" /></li>
     </LoggedInTemplate>
    </asp:LoginView>
</ul>
```

Thanks